# How do I get Eclipse to default to the right font size in SQL Windows on the Mac

Tags: sql, eclipse, macos, font-size

'm using Eclipse IndigoI on Mac OS 10.7 (and 10.6).  Whenever I open up a SQL window (either using SQL Explorer to connect to an SQL DB, or just opening up a foo.sql file), it shows the text in a really small font.  To get it to show in the correct font, I have to select preferences FOR THAT WINDOW, General -> Editors -> Text Editors, click on "Colors and Fonts", select "Text Font", then click on the Edit button, and change the font (because it's ignoring the current setting, and leaving it the same accomplishes nothing).

This gets rather tedious, esp. since I have to do it for each and every SQL text file I open.

Anyone know of a fix for this bug?

Comment: Have you tried this in Eclipse Indigo? I can't reproduce what you're describing; when I set the Text Font it affects the SQL editor immediately and sticks when I close and re-open the .sql file.

Comment: It only sometimes happens w/ .sql files.  It always happens w/ the Files that SQL Explorer opens when I open a connection to a database.  I misspoke, I AM using Indigo.

Comment: It works for me (Eclipse Juno 20120614-1722 in Ubuntu 10.10). The settings I change are used for all the SQL files I open.

Answer (score 1):

Just happened to me on Juno, but instead of smaller text got bigger text font. I fixed it changing it in **General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts -> Basic ->** and selected **Text Editor Block Selection** Font and **Text Font** and changed the font sizes.